# Duplicate net names wire PA1 - Altium designer

Tags: pcb, altium, routing

I have an issue with Altium designer.

I am trying to connect a pin from my microcontroller to an external pin for GPIO via a bus but I get an error: "duplicate net names wire PA1"

This is what I have:

The microcontroller:

[image]

The GPIO pins:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

A complete view of the entire schematic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5j7j.jpg

Comment: What on earth is going on here? It might be reasonable to put a tiny bit of effort into conforming to the way schematics are traditionally drawn. You have components without boxes around them? Or are these floating pins? It appears you've also got alignment issues....? Are you putting things on a standard 10 grid? (the G key)

Comment: @Daniel I am active in embedded software engineering. Never ever drew a PCB. So I'd be glad if you could elaborate what things you think are wrong!

Comment: What is the BoosterPack? Is it a connector? If so you should draw it as a connector rather than a loose collection of pins. That means a box with pins sticking out of it. I don't see the line-waggling issue in imgur that I see in your 'microcontroller' picture, so maybe you don't have alignment issues.

Comment: In some places you have bus entries, in other places you don't. Since your bus is a graphical bus (noted as a comment on the other answer) that doesn't seem to serve any purpose, it would probably be a lot easier to read without it. You appear to be trying to make some kind of hierarchical design rather than a flat design. Read that document linked in the answer and you'll have a much easier time figuring that out. If you just want to avoid it this time, just make sure all the nets that should be connected together have the same name, and things that shouldn't be connected don't.

Comment: Apparently someone has made a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PFxUpbYUrc&t=33s) of this Q&A...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked the properties of your net labels? If they're supposed to connect to other sheets, you'll need to make sure the net label scope is set to "Global" to make sure all net labels AND all ports with the same name are connected together between sheets. You can change the properties of your net labels by going to Project --> Project Options --> Options tab and change the "Net Identifier Scope" dropdown to "Global". Then click OK.

Project --> Project Options:

[image]

"Options" Tab --> "Net Identifier Scope":

[image]

Change dropdown to "Global":

[image]

Comment: Thank you the errors went away. So I guess that was the issue. Just a short follow-up question: when wiring GPIO pins to pins of the microcontroller via a bus (like I am trying to do). Does it mater whether I just use wires to branch off from the busor use a "bus entry" like so: http://imgur.com/a/Sk5ss ?

Comment: It might serve you to get rid of the bus. This is called a 'graphical bus' and doesn't do anything. You can read more about logical buses and graphical buses here http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Connectivity+and+Multi-Sheet+Design

Answer (score 0):

You need to net label your bus as well. Once you do it it will connect busses on different sheets. Bus Net Label = Bus Port Name.